# Unable to connect to MySQL from MySQL Workbench on Linux

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

### Update

It seems the issue is related to reading the password. I tried something, but it's not a totally secure way, maybe someone can explain how to get the password working.

I opened `connections.xml` located under `$USER/.mysql/workbench` and just added my password to the configuration which was initially blank.

```
    <value type="string" key="password">MYPASSWORD</value>
```

Now workbench connects fine, but I don't like this solution. I don't know why workbench doesn't ask me for the password. Also trying to save the password from the GUI to the "Store in Keychain..." option doesn't work and results in the following error:

[image]

#### Original Question

After updating to mysql 8.0.13 on ubuntu 18.04, I am able to connect to mysql from the terminal, but the workbench fails to connect.

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h 0.0.0.0 -P 3306
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 23
Server version: 8.0.13 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

When I try to connect to mysql workbench as root I get the following error dialog.

[image]

Here are my connection settings for the root user:

[image]

I installed version 8.0.13 using the APT repository following instructions from the main website: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Which points to the steps here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

Comment: why don't just named your Hostname as localhost ?

Comment: Based on the screenshots I assume that you're using KDE. In that case try to install gnome-keyring: `sudo apt install gnome-keyring` and try again to connect from MySQL Workbench to a MySQL server.

Comment: try to connect using hostname not ip address, as ip `0.0.0.0` means its listening to global host.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not the problem. The problem is that MySQL Workbench can't find where to fetch/store the password. I agree with @MikeLischke that installing gnome-keyring is worth a try. I'm sure KDE has something similar though, e.g. kwallet.